# Azure KeyVault Service Issue

Tags: azure, spring-boot, sap-cloud-sdk

Currently, Am using Azure keyvault service in one of the application which runs on SpringBoot version 2.3.0.RELEASE
with SAP Cloud SDK version 3.35.0 which is not working with the below configurations in bootstrap.yml . This is required to get the configuration server credentials

```
azure:
  keyvault:
    enabled: true
    uri: 
    client-id: 
    client-key: 
    tenant-id: 
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://test:${config-server-creds}@xxx.com
```

with pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

No logs are printed in the console while Applications boots-up. Any idea on this issue?Is there any Sprinboot versions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a POM file to easily assess the problem.

I checked `com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter:2.3.3` and I found it's referencing `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.2.RELEASE` whereas `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.3.5.RELEASE` would be expected.

In order to establish version compatibility I would suggest to use `com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets:3.1.0`.